# Access page Global JavaScript variable inside my JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below I am trying to access a variable that is set into the page HTML inside of my JavaScript project/objects/app.

`current_user` is the Global variable.

**Page HTML JSON set to JavaScript Global Variable:**

The code is shown below and a JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/Ly8hongf/

I cannot seem to get access to it inside of my app though, please help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var current_user = {
   userid: '123456789',
   name: 'Jason Davis',
   avatar: 'Jason Davis avatar img URL',
}
</script>
```

**Stripped down JavaScript project code:**

```
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    //we cache a few useful values, like jQuery wrapped window and document
    var $window = $(window),
      $document = $(document),

    projectTaskModal = {

        init: function() {
            // init code and functions ran
            this.initCurrentUser();
        },

        // Get Global current_user variable JSON and convert to 
        // local Object Properties in our app
        initCurrentUser: function() {
            console.log('ProjectTaskModal initCurrentUser() Function Ran');

            // get JSON from GLOABL current_user var
            var current_user = $window.current_user;
            // also tried:
            // var current_user = current_user;

            // assign Global JSON into local app JS Object properties            
            var userObj = JSON && JSON.parse(current_user) || $.parseJSON(current_user);

            console.log('userObj.userid', userObj.userid);
            console.log('userObj.name', userObj.name);
            console.log('userObj.avatar', userObj.avatar);

        },

    };

    // Run Init on DOM Ready
    $(function() {
        projectTaskModal.init();
    });

}(this, document, jQuery));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you do:

```
var $window = $(window)
```

...and then your attempt to access `current_user` is:

```
var current_user = $window.current_user;
```

But `$window` is a jQuery object. Global variables are properties of `window`, not jQuery objects. You just want `window` there.

```
var current_user = window.current_user;
// No $ -----------^
```

Alternately, I would just use a different name for the local variable, and make use of the fact that `current_user` is a global:

```
var user = current_user;
```

By not declaring it locally, you don't shadow it, and so you have access to the global.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't think to prepend `window.` even though i;ve seen it a million times! duh thanks again though have been on this for a good half hour now!

Answer (score 1):

There were two issues

1. Don't use jquery wrapped window object. Use `window` instead of `$window`.
2. As the current user is stored as JSON. No need to parse it again using `JSON.Parse`

Fixed JDFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ly8hongf/3/